# Aggregation after sort(), persist() and limit() in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to get the sum of a column of the top *n* rows in a persisted DataFrame. For some reason, the following doesn't work:

```
val df = df0.sort(col("colB").desc).persist()
df.limit(2).agg(sum("colB")).show()
```

It shows a random number which is clearly less than the sum of the top two. The number changes from run-to-run.
Calling show() on the `limit()`'ed DF does consistently show the correct top two values:

```
df.limit(2).show()
```

It is as if `sort()` doesn't apply before the aggregation. Is this a bug in Spark? I suppose it's kind of expected that `persist()` loses the sorting, but why does it work with `show()` and should this be documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the query plans below. `agg` results in an exchange (4th line in physical plan) which removes the sorting, whereas `show` does not result in any exchange, so sorting is maintained.

```
scala> df.limit(2).agg(sum("colB")).explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[sum(cast(colB#4 as bigint))])
+- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_sum(cast(colB#4 as bigint))])
   +- *(2) GlobalLimit 2
      +- Exchange SinglePartition, true, [id=#95]
         +- *(1) LocalLimit 2
            +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
               +- InMemoryTableScan [colB#4]
                     +- InMemoryRelation [colB#4], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                           +- *(1) Sort [colB#4 DESC NULLS LAST], true, 0
                              +- Exchange rangepartitioning(colB#4 DESC NULLS LAST, 200), true, [id=#7]
                                 +- LocalTableScan [colB#4]


scala> df.limit(2).explain()
== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit 2
+- *(1) ColumnarToRow
   +- InMemoryTableScan [colB#4]
         +- InMemoryRelation [colB#4], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
               +- *(1) Sort [colB#4 DESC NULLS LAST], true, 0
                  +- Exchange rangepartitioning(colB#4 DESC NULLS LAST, 200), true, [id=#7]
                     +- LocalTableScan [colB#4]
```

But if you persist the limited dataframe, there won't be any exchange for the aggregation, so that might do the trick:

```
val df1 = df.limit(2).persist()

scala> df1.agg(sum("colB")).explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[sum(cast(colB#4 as bigint))])
+- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_sum(cast(colB#4 as bigint))])
   +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
      +- InMemoryTableScan [colB#4]
            +- InMemoryRelation [colB#4], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                  +- CollectLimit 2
                     +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
                        +- InMemoryTableScan [colB#4]
                              +- InMemoryRelation [colB#4], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                                    +- *(1) Sort [colB#4 DESC NULLS LAST], true, 0
                                       +- Exchange rangepartitioning(colB#4 DESC NULLS LAST, 200), true, [id=#7]
                                          +- LocalTableScan [colB#4]
```

In any case, it's best to use window functions to assign row numbers and sum the rows if their row number meets a certain condition (e.g. row_number <= 2). This will result in a deterministic outcome. For example,

```
df0.withColumn(
    "rn",
    row_number().over(Window.orderBy($"colB".desc))
).filter("rn <= 2").agg(sum("colB"))
```